# Using HTML5 for the content of an email, what is the alternative to an iframe?

Tags: iframe, html-email, email-client

In reference to this article https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2010/08/do-iframes-work-in-email/, which I discovered AFTER I tried to embed an iframe in the body of an email, I need an alternative to an iframe that will work in the body of an email.

The basic problem is I need to provide an anchor with a link to a wav file (actually a cgi script that takes note of the date and time the wav file is requested and then forwards the request to the server that serves up the wav file),but I have been directed to not provide the wav file as an attachment, and to solve the problem that currently my email clients insist on opening another tab before attempting to do anything with the wav file.

I tested the iframe on a static web page, with an anchor that made the iframe the target, and it showed the precise behaviour I was after, but when I did the same thing in the body of the email, the iframe was actually removed and the target was set to '_blank'.

The issues related to google.com and similar not appearing in an iframe are irrelevant because under no circumstances am I showing someone else's content.  Rather, I just want to display content without new tabs/pages opening, and this without using '_self' as the target (because I do not want to force the user off the page containing the link, as the wav file contains references to the content of the email - i.e. they need to be able to see the email while they're listening to the wav file).

Given the apparent hostility of email clients to iframes, what is the best alternative?  It is this interaction of email clients with the HTML body of my emails that makes this different from all the other questions I have seen about iframes.

I repeat, what I have now is valid HTML5 usage of an iframe, and works fine when I serve content from my web server.  My problem is gmail vandalizes/sabotages the content of my emails that use the iframe, as, it appears, do most email clients.

Comment: tldr: Email clients do not universally support iframes - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2010/08/do-iframes-work-in-email/, http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/design/limitations-of-html-email, http://ctrlq.org/help/102-use-iframe-in-html-mail. It might be worthwhile to approach the problem without consideration of such working in another context.

Comment: Indeed.  That is why I am looking for an alternative to the iframe, to produce the same effect, but which will work in email.  But your second link, comparing what works in emails with what works on a website is discouraging since it means my usual approach to printing html contents (which uses a javascript function to use  the browser's services to print) will likely not work in the emails either.

Comment: To be blunt, there is no alternative to what you are looking to do. You are going to need to have them open a new browser window or tab to get them to access or download anything outside what is on the email.  This is done intentionally by email clients to ensure the security of their users.